# Can we replace some part of a text message body in Android?

Tags: android, text, replace, sms

I would like to replace some selected words in all the text messages. I don't necessarily need to modify the original message. I just want to display the new words in the view, instead of the replaced ones.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into regex for that. If you get the message in string form, you can call `replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`. The method returns the modified string, so you can show that new string in the view, instead of the original.

For example:

```
String str = "I want to change what I own";
//modifiedStr is "you want to change what you own"
String modifiedStr = str.replaceAll("I", "you");
```

Comment: Is it possible to display the _modified string_ through the _built-in SMS manager_ of the phone?